# Short story about vampire hunting in a virtual reality game

Tags: story-identification, vampire

This short story centers around a virtual reality type game in which the protagonists are hunting a vampire in a medieval setting. The game doesn't go well for most of the story, but the protagonists win after the noob character shoots the vampire with a silver dagger fired from his crossbow. I believe also that the vampire ended up being the jester type character who had joined their party early on.

Comment: Any recollection of when you read this, or where (a magazine, a collection of stories in a book, etc) would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be "Werewolves of Luna" by R. Garcia Y. Robertson? The story features a group of people and one alien in a virtual reality game where they have to steal a ruby from a vampire's castle. I don't have my copy at hand, but I remember it was a very convoluted plot, beginning with the main character stranded on the moon running out of oxygen and being drafted into the game, and one player is a doglike alien that insists on playing as a werewolf (hence the title).

It was collected in ["The Moon Maid and Other Fantastic Adventures"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0965590186) (1998, ISBN 0965590186) and first published in *Asimov's Science Fiction* in 1994.